# SQL to get processing time of a job

Tags: sql, oracle

There is a job which runs periodically and writes all rows it processed along with the jobid and timestamp in a table

```
Job ID , data, creationtime
1, x1, time1
1, x2, time2
1, x3, time n
2, a1, timea
2, a2, timeb
2, a3, timebn
```

I need a SQL to get the total processing time of a job run eg for jobID 1 , it will be time n- time1

so output could be like :

```
JobID, processing time
1, timen-time1
2, timebn-timea
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ue aggregation:

```
select job, max(creationtime) - min(creationtime)
from t
group by job;
```